# Pullback of differential form under isotopic maps

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms

There's a smooth map $f$ from manifold $M$ to itself which is isotopic to identity (without changing the differential structure). Is there any conclusion we can draw on the form $f^*\tau-\tau$ where $\tau$ is a form on the manifold $M$? Can it be exact?

Answer (score 1):

Without further hypotheses, no. For example, consider $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = 2x$. This map is isotopic to the identity, and $f^*\tau - \tau = 2\tau - \tau = \tau$.

If you assume that $\tau$ is closed, then $f^*\tau - \tau$ is closed and in de Rham cohomology we have

$$[f^*\tau - \tau] = f^*[\tau] - [\tau] = \operatorname{id}^*[\tau] - [\tau] = [\tau] - [\tau] = 0.$$

That is, $f^*\tau - \tau$ is exact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder how the equality$f^*[\tau]=id^*[\tau]$ works out? How to see that isotopic maps keep the cohomology class?

Comment: In general, homotopic maps induce the same map on cohomology. See Proposition 17.10 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (second edition).

Comment: Thanks for the reference.